# how to add/merge values together in a python dictionary

Tags: python

I have two list

```
alist = [1,2,5,3,7,3,21,7,2]
blist = [mary, tom, ken, mary, tom, peter, joseph, mary, ken]
```

in the end I would like to have a python dictionary:

```
{"mary": 11, "tom": 9, "ken": 7, "peter": 7, "joseph":21}
```

adding all their marks together according to their names.

I tried something like this:

```
for (marks, name) in zip(alist,blist):
    dict[name] += marks
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have this solution:

```py
d = dict()
for (marks, name) in zip(alist,blist):
    if name in d:
        d[name] += marks
    else:
        d[name] = marks
```

Maybe something more efficient could be written but I think this works.

Comment: Thanks :). Also the solution given up here with `my_dict[key] = my_dict.get(key, 0) + value`  does the same thing in a slightly more compact way. Maybe better.

Comment: Instead of `if d.get(name):`, `if name in d` makes a bit more sense

Comment: That's right, I changed it. I never think of using `in` for dict keys...

Answer (score 2):

You can use `collections.Counter`, it is probably the most efficient way of doing this.

```
from collections import Counter

c = Counter()
for mark, name in zip(alist, blist):
    c[name] += mark

print(c)
```

Output:

```
Counter({'joseph': 21, 'mary': 11, 'tom': 9, 'ken': 7, 'peter': 3})
```

`Counter` works just like a dictionary, but extends it with some additional methods like:

```
print(c.most_common(3))
```

Output:

```
[('joseph', 21), ('mary', 11), ('tom', 9)]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this solution alternatively

```
alist = [1,2,5,3,7,3,21,7,2]
blist = ['mary', 'tom', 'ken', 'mary', 'tom', 'peter', 'joseph', 'mary', 'ken']
my_dict = {}
for key, value in zip(blist, alist):
    my_dict[key] = my_dict.get(key, 0) + value
```

Answer (score 0):

```
dict(zip(alist, blist))
```

This may help taken from this article https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-convert-two-lists-into-a-dictionary/amp/

Answer (score 0):

> zip(*iterables)
>
> Make an iterator that aggregates elements from each of the iterables.

https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip

```
from collections import defaultdict

alist = [1,2,5,3,7,3,21,7,2]
blist = ['mary', 'tom', 'ken', 'mary', 'tom', 'peter', 'joseph', 'mary', 'ken']

data_dict = defaultdict(int)

for i, count in zip(blist, alist):
    data_dict[i] += count
```

Comment: He wants to add values for the same person, you are getting directly the last value for the same person